# Change navbar background-color depending on the page in React

Tags: css, reactjs, navbar

I have a transparent navbar on my homepage. I would like to give it a black background on every other pages. How would you do that?

Context: React, no Redux.

Comment: what routing system are you using?

Comment: React-router-dom. The navbar is a simple component, directly added to App.js render section.

Answer (score -1):

Just check the route as follows:

```js
  import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
    ...

    const SomeComponent = withRouter(props => <MyComponent {...props}/>);

    class MyComponent extends React.Component {
        ...
        SomeMethod () {
          const {pathname} = this.props.location;
          ...
        }
        ...

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you correctly use react-router-dom, you can wrap your `Navbar` component with the `withRouter` HOC then retrieve the actual location from `this.props.match.path`.

Then it depends on the styling method you use (CSS-in-JS, Styled-Components, Styled-JSX, CSS Modules, etc).

For example, assuming you use CSS-in-JS, in your `render` function you could do this:

```
render () {
  const { match: { path, isExact } } = this.props
  const backgroundStyle = path === '/' && isExact === true 
    ? { backgroundColor: 'transparent' }
    : { backgroundColor: 'black' }

  const navbarStyles = {
    ...styles.navbarWrapper,
    ...backgroundStyle
  }

  return (
    <div style={navbarStyles}>
      {/* Actual NavBar content here */}
    </div>
  )
}
```